# Erro com memcpy e memset

Tags: c

Alguém saberia me dizer porque ocorre esse problema abaixo? Não copia a última posição do vetor de ponteiro, com o valor 57, para outro vetor de ponteiro. Isso me intriga, por que não copia essa última posição?

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int *v;
    int *k;
    k = malloc(100*sizeof(int));
    memset(k,0,sizeof(k));
    k[0]=78;
    k[1]=63;
    k[2]=57;
    v = malloc (10 * sizeof (int));
    memset(v,0,sizeof(v));


    printf("Valor que não quer imprimir no vetor:%d\n",k[2]);
    //*(v+i) = 789;
    //v[i] = 789;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        printf("\nDigite um valor:");
        scanf ("%d", &v[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) printf("%d\n",v[i]);

    printf("\nResultado:");
    memcpy(&v[2],k,sizeof(k));
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) printf("\n%d",v[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Como resultado, essa saída:

```
Valor que não quer imprimir no vetor:57

Digite um valor:1

Digite um valor:2
1
2

Resultado:
1
2
78
63
758396511
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 12.095 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Em memset, não está zerando todos os itens...
Alguém pode me dar uma mão? Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não está inicializando toda a memória alocada com `malloc()`, a chamada de `memset()` está preenchendo com zeros apenas os primeiros bytes do seu *buffer*.

O operador `sizeof()` não vai retornar o tamanho da região de memória apontada por `k`, e sim o tamanho em bytes que o ponteiro `k` ocupa na mémória.

O correto seria:

```
int * k;
k = malloc( 100 * sizeof(int) );
memset( k, 0, sizeof(int) * 100 );
```

A função  `calloc()` da biblioteca padrão `stdlib.h` é capaz de alocar memória e preencher a região alocada com zeros, o que dispensa o uso de `memset()`, simplificando muito seu código:

```
int * k; 
k = (int*) calloc( 100, sizeof(int) );
```

No caso apresentando, a alocação dinâmica de memória não faz sentido algum, a memória pode ser alocada estáticamente, o que dispensaria o uso de `malloc()`, veja só:

```
int k[100];
memset( k, 0, sizeof(k) );
```

Comment: Era só um teste que eu estava fazendo para resolver um problema maior... Obrigada.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema.

Answer (score 1):

O programa está confuso, não consegui entender bem o que ele deve fazer,  mas em relação ao memset o correto é:

```
...
k = malloc(100*sizeof(int));
memset(k, 0, 100*sizeof(int));
...
v = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
memset(v, 0, 10*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: O mesmo vale para o `memcpy`.

Comment: o programa está confuso, não tenho certeza quanto ao memcpy

Comment: Obrigada por responder.
No caso essa parte: memcpy(&v[2],k,sizeof(k));
Ali eu digo para copiar  todo o conteúdo de k para v, a partir da posição 2 de v. Entretanto não são copiados todos os valores de k. A última posição dele não é copiada, não entendo porquê.

Comment: @Bianca Nunes: esta sua explicação não faz sentido, porque o tamanho de v é 10*sizeof(int) e o de k é 100*sizeof(int), então o o que você quer fazer seria "memcpy(&v[2], k, 98*sizeof(int));", então você está querendo copiar 98 ints para um endereço onde existem apenas 8 ints disponíveis! não vai dar erro de sintaxe, mas vai sobrescrever memória que você não alocou; será que "v" não deveria ser declarado com tamanho 100 também ?

Comment: @Bianca Nunes, você está fazendo confusão no "sizeof": quando você faz "sizeof(k)" você está pegando o tamanho variável k, que é um ponteiro, então este tamanho vai ser 4 ou 8 (dependendo da compilação ser 32 bits ou 64 bits(

Comment: Eu fui testando com valores mais altos ali, e esqueci de deixar como estava. Na verdade , antes estava 10. Mesmo assim, o erro permanece, não copia a última posição.

Comment: @Bianca Nunes então coloque uma versão atualizada do seu código, senão vai ser impossível saber o que está errado

Comment: Agora entendi tua explicação mais ali acima. Substituí o sizeof(k) por sizeof(int)*10 e funcionou. Obrigada.

Comment: @BiancaNunes por favor, então marque a resposta como aceita

Comment: Desculpe, onde está essa opção?

Comment: à esquerda, abaixo daquela seta que aponta para baixo, tem um sinalzinho de "ok" que você clica para marcar uma resposta como aceita...veja aqui uma explicação e uma imagem: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta